# shapefile not overlapping patches

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile

I'm building a model which demands me to load shapefiles to netlogo. I've done that and the map that appears on the view corresponds to what it is supposed to. The problem is that the shapefile is not overlapping the the patches. My shapefiles consist of x|y|attribute and I've arround 800 000 lines in the files. The ideal thing was having each line corresponding to a patch but when I execute count patches it has only 1089. And worse, each patch retrieves NaN when I ask for the attribute value. I will paste part of the code that matters to this issue:

```
globals [ mintempcm-dataset
  maxtemphm-dataset
  precipitation-dataset
  meantemp-dataset
  color-list
]

patches-own [
  mintempcm
  maxtemphm
  meantemp
  precipitation
]
to setup
  ca

  gis:load-coordinate-system (word "WGS_84_Geographic.prj")
  set maxtemphm-dataset gis:load-dataset "mxtwm.shp"


  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of 
    (gis:envelope-of maxtemphm-dataset)

  )
  gis:apply-coverage maxtemphm-dataset "MAXTEMPHM" maxtemphm

  ask patches[

    set maxtemphm maxtemphm

  ]

  gis:set-drawing-color blue
  gis:draw maxtemphm-dataset 1


  reset-ticks
end
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? 
To clarify, I need to make each coordinate of the file correspond to a patch and pass the attribute to the patch.

Thanks.

Comment: What data type is your shapefile? If it's just a point x y value, or lines, `gis:apply-coverage` will not work, only polygon data will ([see definition](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html#gis:apply-coverage)). You may want [`gis:intersecting`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html#gis:intersecting).

Comment: Yes, it is x|y|value. I thought apply-coverage would work. I will try gis:intersecting. thanks

Comment: From what i've learned intersecting returns something that intersects with something else. I am trying to assign each point of my shapefile to a patch, i.e., i have coordinate x coordinate y and attribute in my file. I want to make a correspondence between each line of the file and a patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gis:intersecting` to do this, but it's not very efficient for what you want to do. For an example, I downloaded the airports dataset from [this site](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) that has some free gis data. The airports dataset (ne_10m_airports.shp) contains point data  for each airport and some info about each airport. To assign some data to patches, see below- some info in comments:

```
extensions [ gis ]

globals [ airports ]

patches-own [ airport-name ]

to setup
  ca
  resize-world 0 125 0 50
  set-patch-size 5

  ; Load the dataset
  set airports gis:load-dataset "ne_10m_airports.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of airports

  ; For each point listed in 'airports', ask any patches
  ; that are intersecting that point to take the name
  ; of the airport that intersects them (since these are points,
  ; intersection in this case means the airport coordinates
  ; lie within the patch.

  foreach gis:feature-list-of airports [
    x ->
    ask patches gis:intersecting x [
      set airport-name gis:property-value x "NAME"
      set pcolor red
    ]
  ]

  reset-ticks
end
```

You could do this with the "MAXTEMPHM" value from your temperature datasets. However, your NetLogo world size is something you'll have to play around with to make sure that the number of patches corresponds to the number of points you have- `gis:set-world-envelope` only aligns the gis datasets to the NetLogo world, it doesn't affect the patches present. If you have 800000 temperature points you want to load in, you'd need to make your NetLogo world somewhere around 895 patches square, which is a pretty big world. It will take a *while* to load in the temperature data as described above. It would make things simpler and more efficient (and noticeably faster) to use a raster dataset and `gis:apply-raster`.

Comment: I thought converting the data to vector shapefile would make things easier. My original data was in xyz format which is (I think) ascii grid file. Do I have to just change the file's extension to .asc to use it as raster dataset or I will have to use some software like QGIS? Also, is there a way to make correspondence between number of lines in the file and number of patches, or I will have to manually set my world's size (i.e. setting world's max/min-px/ycor) so that number of patches equal the number of points?

Comment: @PauloSergio - If I'm bringing in raster data I almost always keep it in that format, personally. When  you say xyz format, do you mean x column, y column, value column? If so, no you cannot just change the file extension- ASC files are formatted like a matrix [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3x78.png). To get to ASC you would need software (or, technically, the coding know-how). You could programatically set your world size based on the number of lines (see `resize-world` above), but that would be worth a different question, and may not behave exactly the way you'd hope.

Comment: yes. I have x y value. I will try to convert it to asc and then load the data as raster dataset. Thanks for your help and if you have any other tip to make this work feel free to message me or comment